# replace and regex exception

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to wrap all the words of a text in a `<trans>` tag, to be able to work on each words. Hover them, translate on click etc.

For that I need an exception in my replace function to ignore html tags like `<br>` or `<span>`.

Here is the function I have :

```
function wrapWords(str, tmpl) {
  return str.replace(/(?![<br>\<span class="gras">\</span>])[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]+/gi, tmpl || "<trans>$&</trans>");
}
```

This function is working well with russian characters but not with french ones. The problem is that the `<br>` and `<span>` exception is excluding french characters b,r,s,p,a... Because of that some words are not wrapped correctly in my `<trans>` tag.

Does anyone knows how could I exclude a group of characters like specific tags `<br>` for example without affecting letters b and r in french ?

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: Why are you trying to parse HTML using regex, when in fact JavaScript itself is already an HTML parser?

Comment: `[<br>\<span class="gras">\</span>]` is  not what you think it is. It is in fact equivalent to `[ "\/<=>\\abcglnprs]`. (Though I'd definitely listen to Tim and parse HTML properly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properly using DOM, it is a bit more complex, but no corner cases to worry about, as it is very straightforward.

You want to split the text, thus it makes sense to only operate on text nodes. To find all text nodes, we could evaluate an XPath, or we could construct a `TreeWalker`.

Once we know which nodes we want to operate on, we take one node at a time and get all-space and no-space sequences. Each will be transformed into another text node, but the no-space sequences will additionally be wrapped inside a `<span>`. We append them one by one in front of the original node, which will guarantee the correct order, then finally we'll remove the original node, when the replacement nodes are all in their place.

```js
function getTextNodes(node) {
  let walker = document.createTreeWalker(node, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);
  let textnodes = [];
  let textnode;
  while (textnode = walker.nextNode()) {
    textnodes.push(textnode);
  }
  return textnodes;
}
function wrap(element) {
  getTextNodes(element).forEach(node => {
    node.textContent.replace(/(\S+)|(\s+)/g, (match, word, space) => {
      let textnode = document.createTextNode(match);
      let newnode;
      if (word) {
        newnode = document.createElement('trans');
        newnode.appendChild(textnode);
      } else {
        newnode = textnode;
      }
      node.parentNode.insertBefore(newnode, node);
    });
    node.remove();
  });
}

wrap(document.getElementById('wrapthis'));
```

```css
trans {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
Not affected<br/>

<div id="wrapthis">
  This is affected<br>
  <span class="gras">HTML tags are fine</span><br/>
  This as well<br/>
</div>

Not affected<br/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Amadan for showing me another way to do the things. I will work on it and let you know about the result.

Comment: Your code is working fine Amadan. It is still blur for me how it works but I'm starting to understand with firefox documentation and others. Then I will try to customise it for wrapping sentences and not only words.

Comment: Sentences are much harder, as they can be split by elements, or even be at different levels. Consider `<b>Note: This</b> is a <b>sentence. See?</b>`, where it is kind of impossible to wrap the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way:

```
"foo bar baz".split(" ").map(w => "<trans>" + w + "</trans>").join(" ");
```

Explanation:

sentence is splitted by space character, which gives an `Array`. Each element of this `Array` is then wrapped in `<trans>` tags. Then everything is joined to create back a string.

**Edit**: usage in the DOM:

```
var sourceTextNode = document.createElement("div"); // here you're supposed to get an existing node...
sourceTextNode.textContent = "foo bar baz"; // ... and doing this is for the example purposes

sourceTextNode.innerHTML = sourceTextNode.textContent.split(" ").map(w => "<trans>" + w + "</trans>").join(" ");
```

sourceTextNode is:

```
<div>
  <trans>foo</trans>
  <trans>bar</trans>
  <trans>baz</trans>
</div>
```

**Note**: You may want to exclude empty elements in the splitted Array that you'll get when there are multiple consecutive space charcaters.
One way to do this is testing the non-emptiness of the elements in a filter:

```
sourceText.split(" ").filter(Boolean)...
```

Comment: Zim thank you so much for letting me understand the proper way to do the things. Your code is working fine and now I will analyse it to understand it in details.

Comment: Note that this will _delete_ any extant HTML tags that may be present in the node you are transforming.

Comment: Yes it is a quite insufficient answer as it works with plain texts only. Hence the "quick way" introduction...

Comment: @Amadan answer should be the accepted one. But in case of emergency, you'll have the simple way ;)